# Canvas Rotate and Translate problems

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to correctly orient an image uploaded to a canvas from Apple devices. Here's a sample of my code to correctly orient something with EXIF orientation 6

```
ctx.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI);
ctx.translate(0, -canvas.height);
```

This correctly orients the image. However, I need to then write some text and additional drawings to the canvas but they appear upside down. How can I re-orient the canvas to properly draw additional text?

Thank you.

Comment: You will need to return the canvas back to original state, so what you can do is simply do `ctx.save` and then use `ctx.restore` after you have done the rotate and translate, however if you need to keep redrawing the `uploaded` image you will need to rotate and translate every time before rendering that specific image

Comment: @Canvas Oh, wow! That was much easier than I expected. Thank you for your help!

Comment: jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/aLuuk1oa/